# Spark RDD join with Cassandra Table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector

I am joining `Spark RDD` with `Cassandra table` (lookup) but not able to understand a few things.

1. Will spark pull all records between range_start and range_end from `Cassandra table` and then join it with `RDD` in spark memory or it will push down all values from RDD to Cassandra and perform the join there
2. Where the limit(1) will be applied? (`Cassandra` or `Spark`)
3. Will `Spark` always pull same number of records from `Cassandra` no matter what limit is applied (1 or 1000)?

**Code below :**

```
//creating dataframe with fields required for join with cassandra table
//and converting same to rdd
val df_for_join = src_df.select(src_df("col1"),src_df("col2"))
val rdd_for_join = df_for_join.rdd

val result_rdd = rdd_for_join
.joinWithCassandraTable("my_keyspace", "my_table"
,selectedColumns = SomeColumns("col1","col2","col3","col4")
,SomeColumns("col1", "col2")
).where("created_at >''range_start'' and created_at<= range_end")
.clusteringOrder(Ascending).limit(1)
```

**Cassandra table details -**

```
PRIMARY KEY ((col1, col2), created_at) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at ASC)
```

Comment: @Atish it's different API...

Answer (score 2):

`joinWithCassandra` table extracts partition/primary key values from the passed RDD, and converts them into individual requests against partitions in Cassandra. Then, on top of it, SCC may apply an additional filtering, like, you're `where` condition. If I remember correctly, but I could be wrong, the limit won't be pushed completely to Cassandra - it still may fetch `limit` rows per every partition.

You can always check where join happens by executing `result_rdd.toDebugString`. For my code:

```scala
val df_for_join = Seq((2, 5),(5, 2)).toDF("col1", "col2")
val rdd_for_join = df_for_join.rdd

val result_rdd = rdd_for_join
.joinWithCassandraTable("test", "jt"
,selectedColumns = SomeColumns("col1","col2", "v")
,SomeColumns("col1", "col2")
).where("created_at >'2020-03-13T00:00:00Z' and created_at<= '2020-03-14T00:00:00Z'")
.limit(1)
```

it gives following:

```
scala> result_rdd.toDebugString
res7: String =
(2) CassandraJoinRDD[14] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:19 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[2] at rdd at <console>:45 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[1] at rdd at <console>:45 []
 |  ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at rdd at <console>:45 []
```

while if you do a "normal" join, you'll get following:

```
scala> val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((2, 5),(5, 2)))
rdd1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[21] at parallelize at <console>:44
scala> val ct = sc.cassandraTable[(Int, Int)]("test", "jt").select("col1", "col2")
ct: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD[(Int, Int)] = CassandraTableScanRDD[31] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:19

scala> rdd1.join(ct)
res15: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, (Int, Int))] = MapPartitionsRDD[34] at join at <console>:49
scala> rdd1.join(ct).toDebugString
res16: String =
(6) MapPartitionsRDD[37] at join at <console>:49 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[36] at join at <console>:49 []
 |  CoGroupedRDD[35] at join at <console>:49 []
 +-(3) ParallelCollectionRDD[21] at parallelize at <console>:44 []
 +-(6) CassandraTableScanRDD[31] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:19 []
```

The more information is available in [corresponding section of SCC documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#using-joinwithcassandratable).

Comment: from your output, how do you know where the join is happening?

Comment: it happens inside `CassandraJoinRDD` that converts individual values from `rdd_for_join` into separate requests

Comment: My bad, I should have been more clear. What I mean is that how do I know if the join is happening on Spark or in Cassandra

Comment: I tried using the same code twice, one with limit 1 and another one with limit 1000. This is to see how many records are actually pulled into Spark from Cassandra. If the final limit is applied at Spark level then I should get same number of rows pulled into spark for both cases. But from Spark UI, I am not able to understand how many rows are being pulled in both the cases.

Comment: according to the source code, setting limit should add `LIMIT N` to the queries... I you can enable logging of what queries are executed to see what is actually sent to Cassandra...